# Make argument of a function required if a generic type is provided

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create class that I can use for nested collections, hence my functions have the pathArgs and as you can see it is optional, that is because for collections in firebase that are not nested, I do not need any additional paths given.

However, I need this to actually be required if `PathIds` is provided.

```
class FirebaseService<T, PathIds = {}> {
    public findOne(id: string, pathArgs?: PathIds): T { return {} as T };
}

type SomeEntity = {
    hello: "hello"
}
```

So if I do:

```
const firebase = new FirebaseService<SomeEntity>()

// this should be ok, actually pathArgs should NOT be possible to be given to it at all
firebase.findOne("someId"); 
// this should give me an error saying that the function does not accept a second argument
firebase.findOne("someId", { someRandomProp: "" });
```

But if I do:

```
const firebase = new FirebaseService<SomeEntity, { userId: string }>()

// this should now not be okay, and the function should require a second argument
// that is an object and matches { userId: string }
firebase.findOne("someId"); 
// and this should now be the only valid way to call this function
firebase.findOne("someId", { userId: "" });
```

The only difference, is the generics given to FirebaseService

Playground link: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWAnApgI0sgysxA3ewyAPACoA00ACmAC4AWAkgCYwC80A3gL4B8nAUNCHQADgFdUIAtABm8AHZMA8vOQAKeEwBc0CDUQKA5hRG06AQUSGIAfh3V6zCAEodJTtBQ0xieZy7QkNDuXADc-Fz8-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)

**Edit:**

New Playground link: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQFUAOATB0AieCAPACoB8qA3sKnagEYA2CAFgFyqnAC+oksRClQBlAPYBbKKQCemNDXqoEnMAFcJDWAG5ewYBDloACnlYBBGAHMAzmUoBeVAG1SAXVRQAHtDDYbLmBQAG6wHgD8Lh6czphmlrac7rr6wGAIUjZxwgBiYmLU+krYUEgsMGgIDDYQMMgQqGUINgE5IBUMzVAisMEgKGQANKjGqE5BoTCUikr0mGrM-ahw4NgA8kEAFCDYnDUw4FbDAHSnmJymEBbWdsbkAJRJurNzC0xLK37mTEybp8fnEbxG7EO6PLjONzPF6oeaLJCNCp4KCbJBI6BrBgAKwuCBgEBACCYZFQADJqKgdntaodUDxyCczrirglbg9qQcwFZaDC4e8ESUmFBoNtdqh9odGQDmddbKD2ahgmIdtCXnylmocMjRRzJahNbgMdjOFhDVBCBASBQpYDLrK2eClSqeS8XXSivQmi1UG0Ol0AMJiH6lAliMA9GB9AakYajcYhWCUby+fw+9pQTo2bq9fpQIYjaZupTqhFiSYHErLVYbFFU8U0rk2mWs+Xg0iFGGzJBhmqobAMMaoK4gGzHKzC-AMTaYe4pTtKbtgGxBqDHJhiKybfv3D3z1AVCBqGBgag8ZQBUiq2Z8ItzGBiaBIaDYVDjiCTv5MoEskFg3Vcjs90aHsVzXDdpx3ID92FI8TwAIn7Go1DgOA4NvOg+CUG8byAA)

So the solution does work, but now I am getting an error:

`Argument of type '[PathArgs<P>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PathArgs<P>'`

Everywhere where I use the functions, they work as expected now, but this became an internal error.

Comment: @jcalz hello, I have edited and updated with a link in my original post

Comment: You should answer this one @jcalz. Your solution has a signature with arguments `id: string` and mine has `id: string, ...args: never`, which just isn't as nice.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG4Zkw) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I have edited my question and added the new playground link along with the error that I am now getting, I suspect it has something to do with extending the classes, I would also appreciate any tips you might have for how to avoid duplicating the declaration of the types, if at all possible, thank you very much! P.S. Seems like it is simply because one such function is calling another such function

Comment: That's a followup question and really belongs in its own separate post, since you only got that error after your first problem was solved.  `p` is a rest argument so you should be writing `this.getDb(...p)` instead of `this.getDb(p);`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WYR6vw).  There are ways of making that just a parameter and not a rest parameter but it's out of scope here, I think.  Could you [edit] out the followup question part of the post and put it elsewhere if you need more eyes on that?

Comment: @jcalz This fixed it yes! I would definitely seek ways to improve it, but tomorrow, I was struggling with this for a few hours now I can let go of the obsession and sleep :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to have the second type parameter `P` to `FirebaseService` control the [tuple type of a *rest parameter*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) for your methods.  If you explicitly specify `P` it with some type, then the rest tuple should look like `[pathArgs: P]`; otherwise, if it's not specified we can have it [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type
So your class would look like) and then the rest tuple should look like `[]`, the empty tuple.

That is:

```
type PathArgs<T> = [T] extends [never] ? [] : [pathArgs: T];

declare class FirebaseService<T, P = never> {
    public findOne(id: string, ...p: PathArgs<P>): T;
}
```

(the reason we check `[T] extends [never]` instead of `T extends never` is because the latter would be a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and as such would behave unexpectedly).

---

Let's test it out:

```
const firebase1 = new FirebaseService<SomeEntity>()
firebase1.findOne("someId"); // okay    
firebase1.findOne("someId", { someRandomProp: "" }); // error!
// Expected 1 arg, got 2 -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

const firebase2 = new FirebaseService<SomeEntity, { userId: string }>()
firebase2.findOne("someId"); // error    
//        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- Expected 2 args, got 1
firebase2.findOne("someId", { userId: "" }); // okay
```

Looks good! The presence of a second type argument causes a second method argument to be required, and the absence of a second type argument causes a second method argument to be prohibited.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Thank you! So basically, when `extends` is being used in a ternary condition within Typescript, is like `===` so this is like, **is** `T` **a** `never`?, then `[]` is **nothing** or use the type

Comment: Conditional types check for assignability/subtypes, so it's more like `<=`.  (For example `{a: 0, b: 0}` extends `{a: 0}` but they are not equal).  But since `never` is the bottom type, you'll only get `T extends never` if `T` *is* `never`.  And `[]` is the empty [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).